# Powershell 5.0 commandlet Resolve-DnsName invalid packet parsing TTL fields

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, powershell

I have my own DNS server on windows :

My hosts file:

```
stackoverflow.com   IN  A   3605    10.0.0.1
stackoverflow.com   IN  A   3601    127.0.0.1
```

While i testing my server multiple records for a type A or MX with this powershell commandlet :

```
Resolve-DnsName -Server 127.0.0.1 -Name stackoverflow.com -Type A
```

Response:

```
Name                                           Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress                                
----                                           ----   ---   -------    ---------                                
stackoverflow.com                              A      3601  Answer     10.0.0.1                                 
stackoverflow.com                              A      3601  Answer     127.0.0.1
```

The returned '**TTL**' field are ALWAYS the ttl value of the last record. But with this command :

```
>> nslookup -q=A -debug - 127.0.0.1
> stackoverflow.com
Server :   UnKnown
Address:  127.0.0.1

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 2,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        stackoverflow.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  stackoverflow.com
        internet address = 10.0.0.1
        ttl = 3605 (1 hour 5 secs)
    ->  stackoverflow.com
        internet address = 127.0.0.1
        ttl = 3601 (1 hour 1 sec)

------------
Not authoritative answer
Name:    stackoverflow.com
Address:  10.0.0.1
          127.0.0.1
```

Work perfectly.

My server side returned raw datas:

```
00000000   4B DD 81 80 00 01 00 02 00 00 00 00 0D 73 74 61  KÝ.........sta
00000010   63 6B 6F 76 65 72 66 6C 6F 77 03 63 6F 6D 00 00  ckoverflow.com..
00000020   01 00 01 C0 0C 00 01 00 01 00 00 0E 15 00 04 0A  ...À............
00000030   00 00 01 C0 0C 00 01 00 01 00 00 0E 11 00 04 7F  ...À...........
00000040   00 00 01                                         ...
```

Ref:

```
* https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/jj590781(v=wps.630).aspx
```

Conf:

```
Powershell version 5
.NET version 4.7.02556
```

Can anyone confirm powershell '**Resolve-DnsName**' commandlet bad packet parsing please ? thank you.

Observation date :03-29-2018

Comment: No matter if I run `nslookup -q=A -debug stackoverflow.com.` or use a public DNS server with `nslookup -q=A -debug stackoverflow.com. 1.1.1.1` or `nslookup -q=A -debug stackoverflow.com. 8.8.8.8` the TTL on each of the four answers for stackoverflow.com are identical.

Comment: yes because dns is set with the same ttl for stack. I have change this on my host for test.